# ¿Está obsoleto "event.createEvent()"?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Leo en el [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event) que `event.initEvent()` ya está obsoleto.

Pero no dice que `event.createEvent()` también es obsoleto, pero para usar `.createEvent()`, parece que es necesario también usar `.initEvent()`. Entonces, los dos son obsoletos, aunque no lo menciona, o ¿hay otra forma de usar `.createEvent()` sin usar `.initEvent()`?

Comment: Si bien en la [documentación en el español](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) no dice nada, en la [version en inglés](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) hay una aclaración que dice que hay que utilizar [constructores de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) en lugar de `createEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde entiendo tienes razon si el `initEvent` esta obsoleto la creacion del evento no puede darse con esta funcionalidad, es facilmente comprobable

```js
var div1 = document.querySelector("#div1"),
event = document.createEvent("Event");

div1.addEventListener("eventTest", function (e) {
  alert("Ejecuto eventTest");
}, false);

event.initEvent("eventTest", false, false);

event.target = node;

node.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Si se comenta la linea del `initEvent` el evento no se produce.

---

Quizas debas evaluar usar el objeto

[CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)

para crear eventos en reemplazo del `initEvent`

[Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Tambien deberías usar el

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

para asociar el evento al elemento del html

[How to Create Custom Events in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/)

Un ejemplo

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1")

var eventTest = new CustomEvent(
  "eventTest", 
  {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  }
);

div1.addEventListener("eventTest", eventTestHandler, false);

div1.dispatchEvent(eventTest);



function eventTestHandler(){
  alert("paso eventTest");
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```